# Add text underneath inline images

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which puts a bunch of icons (links) in a horizontal line, I was wondering how to add text underneath each image? I've tried using `<br>text</br>`, but then all images to the right of it get put on a newline and I just get a horizontal list. Can anyone offer any help here? I have had this problem repeatedly in the past

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Server Name</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.gif" class="logo-img" />
  </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id="links-container">
    <div class="links" align="center">
      <a href="./forums"><img src="assets/img/Forums.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="http://shop.zentriamc.com"><img src="assets/img/Store.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="./vote"><img src="assets/img/Vote.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="./bans"><img src="assets/img/Bans.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
  </div>
</body><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(assets/img/bk.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 150px;
}
.logo-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
#links-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.links img {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  display: inline;
}
.links img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.links p {
  font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41321369/how-to-add-a-caption-like-text-under-image-in-css

Answer (score 0):

1) Wrap `a` element in `div` with position `relative` and use of `p` with position  `absulote` and set `bottom` and `left` for it.

2)Use of `top` property and `tramsform` property instead of use of consecutive sequence of `br`s.

```css
body {
  background: url(assets/img/bk.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 150px;
}
.logo-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#links-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.links img {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.links img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.links p {
  font-family: "PT-Sans", sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
.cont {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width:20%;
}

.cont p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  width: 100%;

}

#links-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img src="assets/img/logo.gif" class="logo-img" />
</div>
  <div id="links-container">
    <div class="links" align="center">
      <div class="cont">
      <a href="./forums"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></a>
      <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont">
      <a href="./forums"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></a>
      <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont">
      <a href="./forums"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></a>
      <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont">
      <a href="./forums"><img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg"></a>
      <p>Some text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```